# awk get uniques on combined column fields

Tags: awk

I have the following pipe separated file for which I am trying to delete duplicates via `awk`. The duplicate string is column 2 and column 3 concat'ed.

So, I dont want the `name and the organisation` to be as duplicates on the csv

My file looks like so:

```
id|name|org
1|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology
2|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology Department of Applied Physics and Materials Science
3|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology Department of Applied Physics and Materials Science
```

I run:

```
awk -F ' *| *' '!uniq[$2,$3]++' test.csv  >test_out.csv
```

and I get bck:

```
1|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology
```

which seems wrong... I was expecting:

```
1|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology
2|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology Department of Applied Physics and Materials Science
```

Comment: The header line is not present in your expected output - do you really want it removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape pipe char `' *\\| *'` (or put it into a character class `' *[|] *'`) for correct matching:

```
awk -F ' *| *' '!uniq[$2,$3]++' test.csv
```

---

```
id,name,org
1|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology
2|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology Department of Applied Physics and Materials Science
```

Comment: In POSIX terminology `[...]` isn't a character class, its a bracket expression. `[:space:]` is a character class which you can use in a bracket expression, e.g. `[[:space:]]`. I know there's other terminology out there that refers to `[...]` as a "character class" and `[:space:]` as a "POSIX character class" so `[[:space:]]` would presumably be considered a POSIX character class inside a character class but that's as clear as mud - just stick to the POSIX terminology.

Comment: @EdMorton out of curiosity, is using this bracket expresion to `escape` acceotable? I have never heard of it

Comment: @JohnJ it's preferable vs having to double the escapes `' *\\| *'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need either of these depending on whether or not you want the header line printed (and what you'd want to happen if the header values also coincidentally appeared in your data, which may require yet another alternative):

```
$ awk -F ' *[|] *' 'NR==1 || !seen[$2,$3]++' test.csv
id|name|org
1|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology
2|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology Department of Applied Physics and Materials Science
```

```
$ awk -F ' *[|] *' 'NR>1 && !seen[$2,$3]++' test.csv
1|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology
2|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology Department of Applied Physics and Materials Science
```

Note that `-F` is initializing the Field Separator (`FS`) which is a type of Enhanced Regular Expression so if you want any ERE metacharacters in it to be treated literally then you have to escape them. In this case I put the `|` inside a bracket expression as it's clearer than having to double the escapes `' *\\| *'` as you'd have to do otherwise since [that string gets parsed twice](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps), once when converted to a regexp and again when used as that regexp, so one of the escapes gets consumed just in the conversion from string to regexp.

I changed the array name from `uniq[]` to `seen[]` as `seen[]` is the name we idiomatically use for this purpose of determining when the index is first vs subsequently seen in the data. Functionally the name doesn't matter.